# Array Index out of bounds Java program

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Can someone please explain to me why I'm getting an array out of bounds error?

longestStreak : array of booleans -> integer
 Purpose: computes the length of a longest streak of consecutive             true occurrences in the input argument values
 Input  : values is a non-null array of booleans with length at least 1

output : outputs the maximal number of consecutive trues found in          the input array

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Problem3 {

  public static void main (String[] args) { 
    boolean[] test = new boolean[] {true, false, true, true, false};
    int[] o = longestStreak(test);
    System.out.println(o);
  }

  public static int[] longestStreak(boolean[] values) {
    int streak = 0; 
    int max = 0;
    int arrsize = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i]) {   
        streak++;
        max = streak;
        arrsize++;
      }
      else {           
        streak = 0;
      }
    }

    int[] output = new int[arrsize];

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
      for (int z = 1; z < values.length; z++) {
        if (values[i]) {
          i = output[z];
        }
      }
    }
    return output;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post on which line you are getting the exception?

Comment: Acc to your description longestStreak should return int, not int []. Start by changing that. If you still have trouble, update your question.

Comment: @SOlsson The final output im looking for is an array of [2,2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problematic line of code is

```
i = output[z];
```

The reason is because I think that you could be setting i equal to a value that is greater than values.length
Ok, so I reread your problem statement. This code below will fix it for you and it works. just plug it in:
            import java.util.Arrays;

```
  public class Test {


  public static void main (String []args) { 


 boolean[] test = new boolean[] {true, false, true, true, false};

 int[] o = longestStreak(test);
 System.out.println ("{"+o[0] + ", " + o[1]+"}");
  }



    public static int[] longestStreak(boolean[] values) {


 int  streak = 0; 
 int max =0;
 int arrsize =0;
 int maxStart = 0;
 int[] r = new int[2];


 for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   if (values[i]) {   
     streak++;
//     max =streak;
//     arrsize++;
     }

else {
    if (streak > max) {
        max = streak;
        maxStart = 0;
        maxStart = i - streak;
    }
    streak = 0;
   }
 }
 r[0] = max;
 r[1] = maxStart;
 return r;
  }


  }
```

Comment: The final output im looking for is an array of [2,2]. The code is trying to get the position number of I to be the value set at output [z].

Comment: Need more clarification, why [2,2]? is the first 2 the amount of times it is consecutive? What is the second 2?

Comment: The first element is the maximum sequence of true in the initial array. The elements afterwards are the positions where the maximum sequence would start, so in this array it is position 2. So the final output is [2,2]. If the array was [true, false, true, false, true]. then the output would be [1,0,2,4].

Comment: I have made the code do that. Can you check it and then give me the correct answer?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it's the following:

When `values[i]` is `true` the line : `i = output [z];` will try to reach an index which might be greater than `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Should use something like this, instead:

```
public static int longestStreak(boolean... values)
{
   int streak = 0; 
   int max =0;
   for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i)
   {
      if (values[i])
         streak++;
      else
      {
         if (streak > max)
            max = streak;
         streak = 0;
      }
   }
   return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurred because the `values.length` is greater than `arrsize`. Consider following scenario.
In your input, there are 3 `true` values and 2 `false` values. Your code says that `arraysize` will be increment if `values[i]` is true. So here `arraysize` is 3, but `values.length` is the size of boolean array which contains true and false also which is 5. Your inner loop is running up to `values.length` i.e. 5 and your `output` array's size is 3. That's why `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception occurred.

Comment: How could I work around this? The reason why it's looping based on values.length, is because it's checking for the truth values based on the values array.

Comment: Try this : `for (int z = 1; z < arraysize; z++) {` (Ignore if your problem is solved)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
  for (int z = 1; z < values.length; z++) {
    if (values[i]) {
      i = output[z];
    }
  }
}
```

Here *output* array size will be less than *values* array size. Hence it throws *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExecption*.

Here is a modified code that works, using ArrayList.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean[] test = new boolean[] { true, false, true, true, false };

    ArrayList<Integer> o = longestStreak(test);
    for(int x : o) System.out.println(x);
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> longestStreak(boolean[] values) {
    ArrayList<Integer> maxStreak = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int currentStreak = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < values.length; x++)
        if(values[x]) {
            if (++currentStreak == 1)maxStreak.clear();
            if (currentStreak >= maxStreak.size()) maxStreak.add(x);

        } else currentStreak = 0;

    return maxStreak;

}
```

Here is the output (positions of the max streak in boolean array)

```
2
3
```